# Long deploy time of AWS lambda function with huge dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I am building an app using AWS lambda function. My own code logic is very simple: one python file calling some ML functions. On the contrary, it requires a lot of packages (dependencies). I know for smaller cases I can zip these dependencies and upload the zip file for the lambda function. However, it doesn't fit my use case as the zip file can easily exceed the 250 MB size limit. So I have to use the Docker image approach - create a lambda function directly from the Docker image.

I am using sam tool to build / deploy changes. Deploy is very time consuming as it needs to push a very big (6G) image to ECR. The worst thing is I have to endure this every time even making a small changes on my own code and never touching the dependencies.

1. Can I apply the same way as zip approach, i.e, only include dependencies in the docker image and put customized logic out of it? Is it doable?
2. If 1 is not possible, what is the best practice / tips for this? I guess there are some magic in Dockerfile but I am pretty noob here. Any demo / sample codes would be great. I linked my dockerfile below:

```bash
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

RUN python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .
COPY *.py ./

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

I found some suggestions to upload the package to S3 and download it from S3 into tmp folder. This doesn't sound very cool and even if it is, there is also a 512 MB limit which still too small for my use case.

## Update 1

I want to add more context about the app. The app is a prototype to run stable diffusion model. The image is big because it requires bunch of ML packages.

Here is my requirements.txt

```
numpy==1.19.5
opencv-python==4.5.5.64
transformers==4.16.2
diffusers==0.2.4
tqdm==4.64.0
openvino==2022.3.0
huggingface_hub==0.9.0
scipy==1.9.0
streamlit==1.12.0
watchdog==2.1.9
ftfy==6.1.1
replicate
uvicorn
requests
fastapi
mangum
```

I would say the application is pretty similar to [this project](https://github.com/from20020516/serverless-diffusion-discord/blob/main/lib/lambda/Dockerfile) and the dockerfile is also similar.

One tool I found pretty handy is sam cli. When code changes, everytime I just need to run `sam build` (finish in seconds) and `sam deploy` (<5 minutes), which greatly reduces my pain. Also, it has a bootstrap functionality which could set up automatically based on the choice of using zip or image approach.

Comment: The python docker image from `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python` itself is around 600MB. Any specific reason for using that python image? I think that python image contains all the packages and modules required for AWS environment, that's why it is around 600MB. You can try `FROM python:3.9-slim-buster` instead of `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9`.

Comment: please share your `requirements.txt` file or a simple` hello word repo` that covers your large use case.

Comment: @GauravPathak if they are running on Lambda they have to pick an image that has been designed to run on Lambda, or build an image themselves that is designed to run on Lambda. Lambda doesn't run generic docker images, it only runs docker images that implement the AWS Lambda runtime interface. The `python:3.9-slim-buster` image would not run on AWS Lambda. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Comment: @Pentium10 I updated the original post with requirements.txt. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for your comment. I think Gaurav makes a good point that we can leverage customized image. Of course extra config is needed, e.g., set up runtime API. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-alt.

Comment: @GauravPathak Thanks for the suggestion! I will try that and see how much space it would save!

Answer (score 4):

6GB for a Docker image is really a lot, and it will cost you a lot to run it as a Lambda.

There are many things you could try to slim the image down or reorganise your application.

- Remove unneeded code. You could use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) where you pre-build your application in one step and then use a very slim image for the runtime.
- Manage static assets in S3. Upload them before you deploy the Lambda.
- Or, consider using [Lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for generic code. This means, you can pre-deploy generic parts of your application and only update the logic you’re currently working on.
- Another option might be to deploy multiple Lambdas and have them communicate through events or [Function URLs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/).

By the way, have you considered running on ECS rather than Lambda? I don’t know your exact requirements, but this might be more convenient to deploy via ECR and Cloudformation (or, Terraform) as well as potentially more cost efficient in the end. Though the above suggestions (reduce size, extract assets, etc.) would be applicable to ECS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am late to this party with my answer, but here's some tips anyways.

**When using pip+docker, use --no-cache-dir**
You usually won't be installing anything with pip after the image has been built. Therefore, you won't be needing that pip cache.

So instead of:
`RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .`
do:
`RUN python3.9 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt -t .`

**Lambda doesn't need GPU dependencies**
You have `transformers` listed in your requirements.txt. It has `torch` as it's dependency. And `torch` tends to install all sorts of GPU computation stuff, which won't be needed on Lambda, since you won't have a GPU there.

To prevent this, you need to install torch+cpu separately before those transformers' dependencies get installed. Unfortunately, torch+cpu is not available through PyPI, so you need to define it as follows:

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==2.0.1+cpu
```

So your new requirements.txt would be:

```
numpy==1.19.5
opencv-python==4.5.5.64
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==2.0.1+cpu
transformers==4.16.2
diffusers==0.2.4
tqdm==4.64.0
openvino==2022.3.0
huggingface_hub==0.9.0
scipy==1.9.0
streamlit==1.12.0
watchdog==2.1.9
ftfy==6.1.1
replicate
uvicorn
requests
fastapi
mangum
```

Note that you want to make sure that torch+cpu is listed *before* transformers.

These two small changes will slim down your lambda image several GBs, and in most use cases, without any drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea much;

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==2.0.1+cpu
```

Unfortunately I am getting, this;

"python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: 'libc10_hip.so: cannot open shared object..."

Comment: You can try to install `torchvision` separately. E.g. first run:
`pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`. And after that run: `pip install --no-cache-dir torchvision`
The reason is, that the extra-index-url (`-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`) causes also torchvision to be installed from those wheels. And it could just be having some issue when not built locally.

Comment: What do you think about this solution?                                                                                                              ```-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==2.0.1+cpu
torchvision==0.15.2+cpu```                                                                                             It actually resolves this issue.

Comment: If it works (you can successfully invoke the lambda, and it makes your image smaller), I don't see any problem. And good to know that torchvision might need that matching +cpu-wheel as well...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249009/aws-lambda-runtime-wants-to-import-the-wrong-module , @epursiai maybe you?