# AWS Lambda runtime wants to import the wrong module

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, yolov5

I am uploading Docker image to ECR and getting in Lambda;

No module named 'ultralytics.yolo' (Runtime Error, cannot import app.py).

But actually in my app.py there is;

```
import yolov5
from yolov5.utils.general import (cv2, xyxy2xywh)
...
```

There is no ultralytics anywhere in the code however yolov5 is forked from pip installable ultralytics/yolov5 where ultralytics is an dependency;

[yolov5 via pip](https://github.com/fcakyon/yolov5-pip.git)

Part of Docker container directory with dependencies (/var/task);

```
mpl_toolkits                   ultralytics
mpmath                         urllib3
networkx                       werkzeug
numpy                          yaml
numpy.libs                     _yaml
oauthlib                       yolov5
```

Can I somehow translate that?;

ultralytics.yolo == yolov5

Comment: Please show us the Dockerfile and how the requirements are installed - the requirements.txt would be useful. If you could include the full error message that can also help us identify what's going on.

Comment: Thank you Maurice but this appears to be a mismatch between dependencies in (yolov5, utralytics) and ultralytics-yolov5 not AWS. Pain in the a**, I'm afraid you can't help but let you know otherwise..